# Azure Data Lake Gen2 Storage Account blob vs adf choice

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, azcopy

I am new to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 service. I have a Storage Account with "Hierarchical namespace" option Enabled.
I am using AzCopy to move some files and folders. From the command line I can - within the address string - use either the option "blob" or the "adf" string tokens:

'https://myaccount.**blob**.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfolder'

or

'https://myaccount.**adf**.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myfolder'

again within the *.\azcopy.exe copy* command.

"Apparently" both ways succeed giving the same result. My question is: is there any difference if I use *blob* or *adf* in the address string? If yes, what is it?

Also, whatever string token I choose, in the Azure portal a file address is always given with the *blob* string token..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the storage account Endpoint page, you can see all the available endpoints for you to use for their services.

Both `blob` and `dfs` work for you because both of them are supported in `Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2` . However, in Gen1, you may only have the `blob` service but not the `dfs` service available (like below). In that case, you won't be able to use the `dfs` endpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`blob` and `dfs` represent the resource type in the endpoint URL

Comment: ok. but for example using AzCopy I can upload a folder using the *blob* string and download the same resource using the *adf* one and it works! Maybe it is just that the difference between them is not so explicit with AzCopy so I am assessing two different things with wrong tool.